# I can't debug using breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm getting a strange error message in SpringSource Tool Suite (eclipse) when I try to place breakpoints and debug my project, so in this case, when I start Tomcat for debug it shows me the following error message:
"Unable to install breakpoint in bus.GenBUS$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$749137d3 due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.
Reason : Absent Line Number Information"

But I have already controlled and everything is fine in **Preferences -> Java -> Compiler** section (**add line number attr...** is checked). My project is Spring MVC project... Any suggestions ?

Comment: I have also got this error and I just clicked on the `JavaEE` perspective in eclipse and then on `Debug` perspective. Now the error message is gone and I can debug my application.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ignore that. Even if you get that message, the breakpoint is still triggered. This class is temporal, generated by CGLIB. But it still invokes your class, which has the breakpoint.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I've not tried that before. Instead I removed all breakpoints, stopped tomcat, then cleaned both project and tomcat, and build the project again. And before placing it in tomcat I placed some breakpoints. And that's it - there's no error message... very strange :) thanks btw