# Unable to create a breakpoint in Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, compiler-construction, breakpoints

Since yesterday, I get a strange error message when I start my Tomcat (6.0.35) under Eclipse Juno (build 20120614-1722):

[image]

Among the things I tried in order to get rid of the error:

- Check in Preferences -> Java -> Compiler if all "Classfile Generation" checkboxes where checked. I did that for both general preferences and project preference
- Uncheck them, build, check them build again (found on another question)
- Add `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate` to my `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file
- Use a new CVS checkout (same symptoms)

And now, I don't know what to do anymore. The problem is really stopping me from get anything done. I can't work anymore.

Crazy is: the problem doesn't happen on every class, only on some of them. Neither does it happen on my other Eclipse projects. And it didn't happen before yesterday, even if I can't remeber having done anything weird. Actually, I have never seen a problem like this in almost 10 years I'm using Eclipse...

If you have any idea, I would be really grateful...

**Edit:**

I also tried to ignore the message and go on with my tests: If I create another breakpoint upstream from my problematic class, when I enter this problematic class, it tries to open a `$Proxy132` class, which means it actually opens an empty page, with a `source not found` message

Comment: Take a look at this  [SO][1] response to see if it helps 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195091/i-cant-debug-using-breakpoints

Comment: I didn't say it in the question, but I also tried to ignore the message and go on with my tests: If I create another breakpoint upstream from my problematic class, when I enter this problematic class, it tries to open a $Proxy132 class, which means it actually opens an empty page, with a "source not found" message. I will change my question in order to reflect this info.

Comment: @Traroth is the code that is getting deployed on the server compiled through Eclipse or through a build tool such as Ant/Maven

Comment: I currently compile it with Eclipse. I also have a pom.xml, but I'm not using it currently.

Comment: Could you try doing a `mvn install` and use that jar for deployment instead of the eclipse one. This is so that, we can eliminate the case that it is an issue with the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: I guess it might be late already but, how about: running "mvn clean" and making sure that all .class / target folder contents are deleted before building again?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't solve the issue. What I did in the end is install new instances of Eclipse and Tomcat, which was painful, but at least I was able to work again. Actually, a new install of Eclipse didn't solve the issue, but using a fresh install of Tomcat did the trick, so the issue must be somehow Tomcat-related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I would see this kind of message in Eclipse Helios it was because the compile step (Ant in my case) was not set to include debug information.  When using Ant, we had a build.xml file that had a flag stating debug="true".  This would be just a higher-level way of setting the "-g" parameter to javac.  Once I set my debug flag to "true", the "-g" option would be sent to the compiler and the source code would build with line number information included.  This had to be done on all Java files, so if you have modules that aren't compiled automatically as part of a bigger Java process, you will need to make sure those flags get sent to the compiler in those modules as well.  Basically, everywhere you need to debug has to have the "-g" flag set when compiling it.  Hope this helps.